# Error when I Try to Install the New Devel Version of Dplyr - maybe related to Bindr or Bindrcpp packages?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I can't seem to get the new devel version of dplyr to install and work properly. I keep trying to install it from `install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")` and it seems to install ok, then when I try to use it I get the error below. I also tried to install it with `dependencies = TRUE`, but I still got the error. Does anybody know how I can correct this or what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using R 3.3.2.

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
>   versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    there is no package called ‘bindr’ In
>   addition: Warning messages: 1: attributes are not identical across
>   measure variables; they will be dropped  2: package ‘bindrcpp’ was
>   built under R version 3.3.3  Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
>   function 'bindrcpp_RcppExport_validate' not provided by package
>   'bindrcpp'

Comment: It may be better to update your version to `R 3.3.3` and then install it

Comment: Is [bindr](https://github.com/krlmlr/bindr) installed? Did you restart your R session?

Comment: Are bindr and bindrcpp supposed to be dependencies or load with the new dplyr? I installed bindr separately, and bindrcpp is loaded when I use the new dplyr, and the error message disappeared but dplyr::count does not work correctly now. I have another question posted already about this, so I guess that question and this question are related...

Comment: I guess I can try updating to R 3.3.3...maybe that's the simple answer...

Comment: Using binaries built on a different version could possibly cause bugs. You could build them from source, which would fix the issue. If you're going to update, you might as well update to 3.4.0, which came out today.

Comment: What are binaries and what does building them from source mean? Also, what's the easiest way to update R without changing all my packages and everything. I don't have much experience with this...